# Запятая перед "плюс"

Tags: пунктуация

Когда в предложении "плюс" употребляется в значении "и", нужна ли перед ним запятая? Например: "Я купил лекарства(,) плюс к этому мне нужно купить продукты".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сложносочиненное предложение. Даже если было бы "и", ставилась бы запятая. В вашем случае "плюс к этому" - это, должно быть, союз, употребленный, как вы правильно сказали, в значении "и", следовательно запятая нужна. Если бы было предложение типа: "Мне дано купить лекарства плюс продукты", то запятая не ставилась бы.

Answer (score 3):

Конечо, нужна. Предложение сложное: я купил, и (плюс) надо купить.