# После слова "плюс" нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Плюс легкие румяна на слегка впалых щеках, помада, ровный контур губ и туш на длинных ресницах, которые нанесла на лицо девушка, еще больше сбивали с толку.

Comment: О запятых до и после слова "плюс" также см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39429/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%81,  
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5768/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%81,  
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32145/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%81

Answer (score 3):

Да зачем же?!

*Коля + Оля = никогда, или Сыграем туш!*

К чему после добавления чего бы то ни было громоздить знак(и)?!

*Плюс лёгкие румяна на слегка впалых щеках, помада, ровный контур губ и тушЬ на длинных ресницах, которые нанесла на лицо девушка, ещё больше сбивали с толку.*

Меня очень сильно напрягают ***ровный контур губ и тушь на длинных ресницах, которые нанесла на лицо девушка***, хоть караул кричи.

В общем, переписывайте сочинение и явите вновь пред наши очи.

---

Хозяйке на заметку:

> **Тушь** – представляет собой красящее вещество. Это существительное женского рода, третьего склонения. Согласно правилам русского языка на
>   конце таких существительных после шипящих пишется мягкий знак.
>
> *Засохшую тушь для ресниц можно реанимировать.*
>   *Мне подарили новую тушь для ресниц.*
>   *Для выполнения чертежа нужна черная тушь.*
>
> ---
>
> **Туш** – представляет собой музыкальное произведение в форме марша. Это существительное мужского рода, второго склонения. Согласно
>   правилам русского языка на конце таких существительных после шипящих
>   мягкий знак не пишется.
>
> *Туш грянул так громко, что проснулись все.*
>   *В честь юбиляра прозвучал туш и вынесли огромный букет.*
>   *После первой репетиции хорошо получался у нас только туш.*

**[источник](https://kak-pravilno.net/tush-ili-tush-kak-pravilno/)**

Comment: Ещё бывает _контур **туш**_, освежевАнных львом в саванне. :)

Comment: Пока не прочитал Ваш ответ, никак не мог понять технологию нанесения ресниц на лицо :)

Comment: Сашка, как всегда, ёрничает - стихами разговаривает (я ритм поймала), а Гриззли - лукавишь, нема тут технологии! Учу жить: наносим тонкий слой туши - снизу верхних ресниц (нижние вообще лучше не красить), даём высохнуть; то же, но сверху и обратно же сушим; возвращаемся к низу верхних, сушим - и так до наращиванья пары сантиметров. Ой-ё, grizzly, ты тоже хорош ёрник, тока щас дошло!... Поставь мне скорее пятёрочку за вопрос - меня какой-то гад сминусовал, сделал чётной!

Answer (score 3):

Если поставить запятую, то получится, что этот плюс был нанесён на лицо вместе с румянами и тоже сбивал с толку.

Comment: У, змий. Остряк нищасный.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, этот "плюс" стилистически неудачно употреблен. Обычно после "плюс" следует дополнение, отвечающее на вопрос *что?*, а у Вас - сложное предложение.

Как вариант исправления: можно добавить слова *ко всему* (получится *плюс ко всему*) или *к этому* (получится *плюс к этому*). Постановка запятой после таких выражений — вопрос непростой, я задавал его [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436918/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83). В данном случае я бы запятую поставил:

**Плюс ко всему,** легкие румяна на слегка впалых щеках, помада, ровный контур губ и **тушь** на длинных ресницах, которые нанесла на лицо девушка, еще больше сбивали с толку.

P.S. Ресницы наращивают, а не наносят на лицо, но это я оставил на совести автора. Скорее всего, автор имел в виду румяна, помаду и тушь, которые девушка нанесла на лицо, а получилось, то девушка нанесла на лицо ... ресницы.