# Выделять ли запятыми "плюс ко всему"?

Tags: пунктуация

Встретил утверждение, что "плюс ко всему" не следует выделять запятыми. Всегда ли это верно?

Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**Плюс ко всему** ― даже в мире улиток их кличут улитками. [Топ-10 видов // «За науку», 2014]

«Тут и одичавшие собаки, и люди, которым больше некуда идти, и, **плюс ко всему**, солдаты с оружием в руках, которые с утра до вечера ходят по домам в поисках новой жертвы, объясняя это тем, что делают проверки. [Борис Рогинский. Голубой вагон // «Знание - сила», 2005]

**Плюс ко всему**, нового вида имплантанты сделаны с шероховатой поверхностью (текстуированные, а раньше были гладкие) которые препятствуют затвердению и образованию капсулы. [Красота, здоровье, отдых: Красота (форум) (2005)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что писал Розенталь (синонимичные сочетания здесь выделены мной):
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

> *Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми слова и словосочетания: авось, буквально, будто, **вдобавок**, **в довершение**, вдруг, ведь,
>   в конечном счете, вот, вряд ли, все-таки, далее, едва ли,
>   исключительно, именно, как будто, как бы, как раз, **к тому же**,
>   между тем, небось, по предложению, по постановлению, по решению,
>   приблизительно, примерно, притом, почти, поэтому, просто, решительно,
>   словно, якобы и др.*
>
> Встречающийся применительно к этим словам пунктуационный разнобой
>   связан с различными причинами: в одних случаях сказывается то
>   обстоятельство, что некоторые из перечисленных слов относятся к так
>   называемым модальным частицам, которые могут употребляться и как
>   частицы и как вводные слова; в других играют роль смысловые оттенки,
>   присущие отдельным словам и допускающие их обособление; наконец,
>   возможно влияние прежних правил или индивидуальной авторской
>   пунктуации.

Далее там приводится пример того, как в некоторых контекстах словосочетание **в довершение всего** (синонимичное нашему) *может* быть употреблено в функции вводного:

> а)  *В довершение всего* начался дождь (Чехов);
>
> б)  И, *в довершение всего*, ни вилок, ни ножей (Салтыков-Щедрин).

Из этого следует, что рассматриваемое синонимичное словосочетание **не следует отделять запятой**, *если нет особых оснований* считать его вводным. Последнее возможно при передаче сбивчивой разговорной речи, например:

> Этот рассеянный прохожий, **плюс ко всему**, рассеивал семечки по
>   асфальту.

Answer (score 2):

По приведенным из Нацкорпуса примерам, выражение "плюс ко всему" - это вводное сочетание, использующееся тогда, когда автор хочет привлечь внимание читателя к содержанию сообщения. На мой взгляд, оно равнозначно вводному сочетанию "кроме того". Пример: *Я ел собак, кошек, мышек и, плюс ко всему (кроме того), тараканов.* 
[Словарь вводных слов под редакцией Фрамполя](http://%09%20twirpx.com/file/1580803) указывает на то, что выражение "плюс ко всему" - это "наречное выражение в функции присоединительного союза. Оно не обособляется".

Comment: Равнозначно "как по мне"?!

Comment: Равнозначно сочетанию "кроме того".

Comment: Простите за правку, не понял Вашей мысли сразу. Всё-таки "как по мне" очень непривычное и странное вводное выражение. Надеюсь, Вы не против того, как я только что переписал.

Comment: "Как по мне" схоже по значению с "на мой взгляд". Указывает на то, что высказывание - личное мнение автора.

Comment: Да я понимаю, Иван. Просто очень нелитературное оно.

Answer (score 1):

Все мы знаем, что вводные слова могут при определенных условиях являться обстоятельствами, и тогда они не обособляются.

**Вводными словами можно назвать наречные выражения определенной тематики,** которые  обычно обособляются, причем эти наречные выражения автор помещает в такую позицию, где их удобно обособить.

Рассмотрим выражение ***плюс ко всему***, можно ли его считать вводным словом? По значению  оно скорее близко **к словам включения/исключения,** а это не тематика вводных слов. Такие выражения **часто обособляются**, особенно если грамматически не связны с членами предложения  (например, ***кроме того***), но **могут и не обособляться**.

**Плюс ко всему** ― это  ***вдобавок к этому***.   Эти словосочетания при определенной структуре предложения о**бособляться могут**. Можно предположить, что частотность вариантов примерно равная.

Таким образом, эта падежная форма **ведет себя стандартным образом**.

**Примеры:**

Плюс ко всему ― золотовалютные резервы падают (за последнюю отчетную неделю ― на 1, 7 млрд. ). **Плюс ко всему**, нам давно не прибавляли заработную плату.

**Плюс ко всему** есть несколько стран, где абсент не запрещен.